# Do I need to train models for CMUSphinx for Indian English

Tags: speech-recognition, sphinx4

I am making a speech based web browser.
I need it to recognize words from a list of about 50 isolated English words spoken in Indian accent. Should I use the acoustic model or the language model to train it?
The words would be like, "Sports","Headlines","Back".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use the acoustic model or the language model to train it? The words would be like, "Sports","Headlines","Back".

You need to make both acoustic model and a language model (or grammar).